# Dynamic Filtering - Spring-Boot

Tags: java, jackson, filtering

My requirement -
I have a Entity, in which i don't want to filter any field in one API (say API A), and filter all but password field in another API (API B). Is there any way i can do this not configuring the filter in API A as that requires this line of code

```
SimpleBeanPropertyFilter filter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("id","userName","userPassword","emailVerificationStatus" );
```

where i have to explicitly mention all fields, which is bad because then i have to do it everywhere.
I have used @JsonFilter("userPasswordFilter") in the Entity class.

i get this exception when i run my API A -

```
in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class com.tester.demojar.entities.FplUser]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot resolve PropertyFilter with id 'userPasswordFilter'; no FilterProvider configured] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot resolve PropertyFilter with id 'userPasswordFilter'; no FilterProvider configured
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1276) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.findPropertyFilter(StdSerializer.java:426) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
```

Entity -

```
@Entity
@JsonFilter("userPasswordFilter")
@Table(name = "FPL_USER")
public class FplUser {

@Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "FPL_USER_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 100)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "FPL_USER_SEQ", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "JPA_ID")
    private long id;

    @Size(min = 5, message = "UserName minimum length = 5")
    @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
    private String userName;

    @Size(min = 8, message = "userPassword minimum length = 8")
    @Column(name = "USERPASSWORD")
    private String userPassword;

    @Column(name = "USER_EMAIL_VERIFICATION")
    private char emailVerificationStatus;
```

Service class - **API A**

- **PLEASE NOTE : If i uncomment my lines of code below it works, but why do i have to configure the filter when i want all the fields.**

```
public MappingJacksonValue getDetailsOfUser(long jpaId) {
        if(fplUserRepo.findById(jpaId).isEmpty()) 
            throw new FplUserException("id nahi mila-" + jpaId, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

        FplUser fplUser = fplUserRepo.findById(jpaId).get();
//      SimpleBeanPropertyFilter filter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("id","userName","emailVerificationStatus","userPassword" );
//      SimpleFilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("userPasswordFilter", filter);
        MappingJacksonValue response = new MappingJacksonValue(fplUser);
//      response.setFilters(filters);
        return response;
    }
```

i don't want to put filters for API A,  as i need all of them.
But for API B, my filter works.

My Question is how do i avoid this filter when i need all the fields ?